# why do I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused?

Tags: java, smtp, mime, postfix-mta, jakarta-mail

I'm able to send mails to myself (not sending over the intertubes), yet cannot seem to use Java to replicate as below.  Postfix via telnet behaves fine:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
helo me
250 dur.bounceme.net
mail from:<someone@somewhere.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
subject: hmm, is this smtp?
how do I do this from Java?
there's no password...
postfix-dovecot
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 81A9717FEB0
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Here's the stack trace in Java, all I can see is that it's `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` but I don't know why:

```
Feb 23, 2013 3:03:29 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender send
SEVERE: {0}
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: dur.bounceme.net, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1962)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.send(MessageSender.java:57)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.populate(MessageSender.java:46)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.MessageSender.<init>(MessageSender.java:30)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.ArticleReader.<init>(ArticleReader.java:28)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:13)
    at net.bounceme.dur.nntp.Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1928)
    ... 8 more

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

relevant code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MessageSender {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessageSender.class.getName());
    private String header;
    private String body;
    private Properties p;
    private Session session;
    private MimeMessage message;

    private MessageSender() {
    }

    public MessageSender(Properties p, String... s) throws Exception {
        header = s[0];
        body = s[1];
        this.p = p;
        populate();
    }

    private void populate() throws Exception {
        String lines[] = header.split("\\n");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);
        message = new MimeMessage(session);
        LOG.fine("\n\n\n\nnew message************\n\n\n\n");

        for (String s : lines) {
            message.addHeaderLine(s);
        }
        message.setContent(message, body);
        String recipient = p.getProperty("recipient");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        send();
    }

    private void send() {
        try {
            String protocol = p.getProperty("protocol");
            String host = p.getProperty("host");
            int port = Integer.valueOf(p.getProperty("port"));
            String username = p.getProperty("username");
            String password = p.getProperty("password");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport(protocol);
            transport.connect(host, port, username, password);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        } catch (MessagingException  ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0}", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Java-Mail, but the `ConnectException: connection refused` usually occurs when there is no service running on the specified port.

Comment: port 25 is smtp, I believe.  I'm able to send messages via telnet port 25, so the service (postfix-dovecot) seems to be running.  The e-mail shows up in Thunderbird.  (The FQDN dur.bounceme.net is only for my usage, it's not a "real" host.)

Comment: I'm not sure, I totally understand you. You can send messages via telnet on port 25 which would mean there's a telnet service running on port 25. So it's not possible to have a smtp-service running on port 25 as well, which means you get the refuse because the telnet service can't accept smtp-messages.

Comment: I don't think so.  According to http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/8/6/postfix-using-telnet-to-test-postfix the way to test postfix, and smtp with it, is to use telnet to do so.  They specify `telnet mail.demoslice.com 25` as an example command for this purpose, but maybe that's different because it's slicehost.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't know that you could telnet to send email. Could you maybe post what properties you are setting to the MessageSender?

Comment: the problem was that I using `localhost` with telnet but with Java was getting an error about `SMTP host: dur.bounceme.net, port: 25;` now, the host is `dur.bounceme.net` but I don't get a connection error anymore by changing the `host` property for MessageSender to read `localhost`.  My recollection is that I should be able to use the FQDN `dur.bounceme.net` but it's a relatively minor point and I'm no longer getting a connection error.  (I get a brand new error about some of the headers being invalid, LOL.)  Mystery solved, I think.